# Counterexample: There exist non-zero nilpotent matrices $A$ and $B$ that $AB$ is non-negative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

I am asked to prove or state a counterexample for the following statement:

There exist non-zero nilpotent matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB$ is non-negative.

Any ideas would help a lot as I'm not able to come up with a counteraxample. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at

$$A =\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},\space\space\space
B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$